# How to interact with element based on media query?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

How do I interact with named elements via media queries?  The following doesn't work.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media (max-width : 320px) {
#footer {display:none;}
#myimage {display:none;}
}
```

in the page

```
<div id="footer">...</div>
<img id="myimage" src="..."/>
```

Comment: Do you have a demo of this not working?

Comment: It's working for me, resize your browser to see it disappear: http://jsfiddle.net/SHeEw/embedded/result/ and make sure you are using a browser that supports css3.

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @4thSpace It works for me when I resize my window to below 320px. Which browser/version are you using?

Comment: Actually, I see the issue.  Safari's min browser width is only 400px.  Uhg!  It does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code you provided does work when put in a fiddle. The footer and myImage elements disappear when the page is smaller than 320px.

I set up a cleaner version of content being altered with media queries.

http://jsfiddle.net/bXenf/

```
/* The magic happens here. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #block1 { display:block; }
    #block2 { display:none; }
}
```